# Advice how to do audit with some entity fields

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, attributes

i am looking for another way that how can i set those fields through database instead of doing in service layer all the time one by one :)
I wonder if i can make all those by using custom attribute or is there any extension that i can handle those stuff ?

```
public interface IBaseEntity
{

    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    string CreatedIpAddress { get; set; }
    string CreatedMachineName { get; set; }

    DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    string UpdatedIpAddress { get; set; }
    string UpdatedMachineName { get; set; }
    
    DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }
    string DeletedIpAddress { get; set; }
    string DeletedMachineName { get; set; }
    Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

as shown below i set those fields manually like that;

```
public void Delete(int id)
    {
        Category category = _categoryRepo.GetDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        category.DeletedDate = DateTime.Now;
        category.DeletedMachineName = Environment.MachineName;
        category.DeletedIpAddress = CatchIP.IpAddress;
        category.Status = Status.Passive;

        _categoryRepo.Delete(category);
    }
```

appreciate all the advice and information since i've been just writing for 4 months :)

Comment: The biggest stumbling block for each grouping will be the IP address: how can SQL Server determine the IP address of the client that's sitting on the other side of your service layer? That, at least, is something that the service layer needs to provide to SQL Server.

Comment: What's the problem you're actually trying to solve here? Are you trying to avoid DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) in your entity class code? Is there a way you could use `generics` to provide the implementation of your insert/update/delete audit functions? Could they be added to a base class from which your entity classes are subclassed? Since they're likely identical (except for class names) on each entity class, could you just code generate them into a set of `partial class` files?

Comment: Yea generics can work i guess. I was just trying to see if there are tools for stuff like that or any  other way :) Trying to avoid DRY and learn new implementation basicly :) Thanks for advice @AlwaysLearning